# How do I get a PTR record for an MX that points to a different IP than the A record does?

Tags: networking, email, dns, dns.ptr

MXToolbox indicates a warning that my smtp server's header banner fails to match reverse lookup for the stated domain.

This makes sense - I've got a domain with the MX set to one IP (my mail server), but the A record is set to the web host.

Is it possible to setup a PTR record such that the MX can resolve properly as well on a reverse lookup?

**EDIT: I'm going to expand my question because my scenario maybe isn't clear:**

```
my-domain.com  
A     123.123.123.123
MX    my-ddns-name
CNAME mail my-ddns-name
```

So I can see adding a PTR record  for my-domain.com, which has an actual static IP.

But how do I implement a PTR record so that my-ddns-name reverse lookup generates my-domain.com?

What I want is to send & receive emails:

`steve@my-domain.com`

And my email server - pointed to as the MX for my-domain.com, is not actually even in my-domain.com, but is hosted via a DDNS (of course it could be hosted via a static IP if I pay for another domain).

But I still want my emails to refer to my-domain.com, while attempts to http: to that domain should result in connecting to my web server, and attempts to send or receive email should redirect to my fully-complaint smtp server on a different domain (but should operate fully as if it were the publicly named domain).  It's purely a matter of hosting web stuff one place, but email another place.

***I don't grock how to do the PTR record for this?***

Comment: Have you considered more than one PTR record fot the IP address?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's usually done like this:

```
          example.com      A  192.0.2.1
          example.com     MX  mail.example.com
     mail.example.com      A  192.0.2.2
1.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa   PTR  example.com
2.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa   PTR  mail.example.com
```

That way, mail.example.com points to 192.0.2.2, and 192.0.2.2 points back to mail.example.com, and everyone is happy.

Comment: I think my stumbling block is that I don't actually have access to the DNS table for my mail server host - I'm just redirecting the MX to a DDNS based IP managed by Synology.  I'll try adding a PTR in my Freehostia's DNS table, where my domain is hosted for the current value of the DDNS redirect, but I'll bet that's going to be inadequate on two levels: 1 - because it's the wrong DNS table, and 2 - when the DDNS changes IP it'll be misconfigured, no?